# Re-render a component in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, gatsby, render

I'm using react and I can't find how to conditional render this example in gatsby.
The main goal is re-render the child component every time I changes in value but I don't want to re-render all the website only the Child component

```
import * as React from "react"
    
    let i=1;
    
    const Test = () => {
      return (
        
        <main>
        <button onClick={()=>{i=i+1;console.log(i) }}>CLICK ON ME</button>    
        <Child></Child>
        </main>  
               
                  
            
      )
    }
    
    export default Test
    
    const Child = () => {
        if(i===1){
            return(
            <div >
                1
                </div>
            )
        }
        if(i===2){
            return(
            <div >
                2
                </div>
            )
        }
        if(i===3){
            return(
            <div >
                3
                </div>
            )
        }
        else{
            return(
            <div >
                4+
                </div>
            )
        }
      
      
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gatsby is a React-based framework, it uses React under the hood so the component and state management is identical to Reacts.

In your case, try using a `useState` hook to render the `Child`, passing the integer as `props`:

```
   const Test = () => {
     const [i, setI] = useState(1)

      return (
        <main>
        <button onClick={()=>{setI(i+ 1);console.log(i) }}>CLICK ON ME</button>    
        <Child i={i} />
        </main>  
      )
    }
```

In the `Child` component:

```
const Child = ({ i }) => {
  return <div>{i}</div>
}
```

If you want to conditionally render different components depending on i valu, just use:

```
const Child = ({ i }) => {
  return <>
  {i==1 && <div>Some rendered content when i==1</div>}
  {i==2 && <div>Some rendered content when i==2</div>}
  </>
}
```

React's state management will only rehydrate (render) the needed parts that have changed accordingly. In this case, because you are changing the `i` value with the `setI` function, it will rehydrate the child changing the value lifted using `props`.

Comment: I tried that solution but I'm having this error https://imgur.com/a/eGVx4MG
`
Unhandled Runtime Error
Close
One unhandled runtime error found in your files. See the list below to fix it:


Error in function _readOnlyError in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/readOnlyError.js:2
"i" is read-only

./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/readOnlyError.js:2
Open in Editor
  1 | export default function _readOnlyError(name) {
> 2 |   throw new TypeError("\"" + name + "\" is read-only");
  3 | } `

Comment: I solved it setting the const as a var but I have a problem, the UI didn't re-render at click it re-render several clicks after, exactly 3 clicks after

Comment: You shouldn't, the idea is not to use const or vars, is to use React's state to force the re-render. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html